# Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute on formArrays

Tags: loops, angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to iterate over a formArray in my component but I get the following error

`Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute`

Here is what the logic looks like on my class file

```js
export class AreasFormComponent implements OnInit {
    public initialState: any;
    public areasForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

    private area(): any {
      return this.fb.group({
          name: ['', [Validators.required]],
          latLong: ['', [Validators.required]],
          details: ['', [Validators.required]]
      });
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.areasForm = this.fb.group({
            name: ['', [Validators.required]],
            areas: this.fb.array([this.area()])
        });
    }
}
```

and my template file

```xml
<form class="areas-form" [formGroup]="areasForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(areasForm.values)">
    <md-input-container class="full-width">
        <input mdInput placeholder="Location Name" type="text" formControlName="name" required>
        <md-error *ngIf="areasForm.get('name').hasError('required')">Please enter the locationName</md-error>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-grid-list cols="1" [formArrayName]="areas">
        <md-grid-tile formGroupName="i"  colspan="1" rowHeight="62px" *ngFor="let area of areasForm.controls.areas.controls; let i = index ">
            <md-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="60px">
                <md-grid-tile colspan="1">
                    <md-input-container class="full-width">
                        <input mdInput placeholder="Area Name" type="text" formControlName="name" required>
                        <md-error *ngIf="areasForm.get('areas').controls[i].name.hasError('required')">Please enter the area name</md-error>
                    </md-input-container>
                </md-grid-tile>
                <md-grid-tile colspan="1">
                    <md-input-container class="full-width">
                        <input mdInput placeholder="details" type="text" formControlName="details" required>
                        <md-error *ngIf="areasForm.get('areas').controls[i].name.hasError('required')">Please enter the locationName</md-error>
                    </md-input-container>
                </md-grid-tile>
                <md-grid-tile colspan="1">
                    <button md-fab (click)="remove(i)"><md-icon>subtract</md-icon>Remove Area</button>
                </md-grid-tile>
            </md-grid-list>
        </md-grid-tile>
    </md-grid-list>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="areasForm.invalid" md-raised-button color="primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Remove the brackets from

```
[formArrayName]="areas"
```

and use only

```
formArrayName="areas"
```

This, because with `[ ]` you are trying to bind a **variable**, which this is not. Also notice your submit, it should be:

```
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(areasForm.value)"
```

instead of `areasForm.values`.

Comment: Is your plunkr broken?

Comment: and yet [FormGroup]="areasForm" is correct?  Angular is really kicking me in the pants....

Comment: The curly brackets were the problem in my case with the formGroupName

Comment: @greg late to comment... `[formGroup]="areasForm"` is correct because `areasForm` is a variable in your component TS, whereas `areas` is not. It is property of the `areasForm` :)

Comment: I had this error pointing to row "106" in my template. It turned out that the formControl *before that line* was misspelled! So this error is saying that error is at row X, when it is actually before that.
Oh btw, upgrade to 14+ if you can. It has typed forms!

Answer (score 26):

In my case I solved the issue by putting the name of the formControl in double and sinlge quotes so that it is interpreted as a string:

```
[formControlName]="'familyName'"
```

similar to below:

```
formControlName="familyName"
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I kept seeing the formControlName wrapped in single quotes but the difference between passing it as a string vs the formControl object didn't click until seeing this.

Answer (score 11):

The problem for me was that I had

```
[formControlName]=""
```

Instead of

```
formControlName=""
```

Comment: I needed to change from [formControl] to formControlName

Answer (score 7):

Instead of

```
formGroupName="i"
```

You must use:

```
[formGroupName]="i"
```

**Tips**:

Since you're looping over the controls, you've already the variable `area`, so you can replace this:

```
*ngIf="areasForm.get('areas').controls[i].name.hasError('required')"
```

by:

```
*ngIf="area.hasError('required', 'name')"
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to be part of the problem but the answer above solved my issue.

Answer (score 7):

For me, I was trying to add `[formGroupName]="i"` and/or `formControlName` and **forgetting to specify the parent `formArrayName`**. Pay attention to your form group tree.

Comment: I was using both as well. Remember to put the `formArrayName` on a DOM-element higher up in the hierarchy than `[formGroupName]="i"` (e.g. on the loop element:  `<div *ngFor=let ctrl of formArrayCtrl; let i = index"><div [formGroupName]="i"></div></div>`)

Comment: **Pay attention to form group tree** helped me.

Answer (score 4):

This was happening for me because I had `fromArrayName` instead of `formArrayName` somewhere

Answer (score 3):

So, I had this code:

```
<div class="dropdown-select-wrapper" *ngIf="contentData">
    <button mat-stroked-button [disableRipple]="true" class="mat-button" (click)="openSelect()" [ngClass]="{'only-icon': !contentData?.buttonText?.length}">
      <i *ngIf="contentData.iconClassInfo" class="dropdown-icon {{contentData.iconClassInfo.name}}"></i>
      <span class="button-text" *ngIf="contentData.buttonText">{{contentData.buttonText}}</span>
    </button>
    <mat-select class="small-dropdown-select" [formControl]="theFormControl" #buttonSelect (selectionChange)="onSelect(buttonSelect.selected)" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngClass]="{'selected-option': buttonSelect.selected?.value === option[contentData.optionsStructure.valName]}" [disabled]="buttonSelect.selected?.value === option[contentData.optionsStructure.valName] && contentData.optionSelectedWillDisable" [value]="option[contentData.optionsStructure.valName]">
        {{option[contentData.optionsStructure.keyName]}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </div>
```

Here I was using standalone formControl, and I was getting the error we are talking about, which made no sense for me, since I wasn't working with formgroups or formarrays... it only disappeared when I added the *ngIf to the select it self, so is not being used before it actually exists. That's what solved the issue in my case.

```
<mat-select class="small-dropdown-select" [formControl]="theFormControl" #buttonSelect (selectionChange)="onSelect(buttonSelect.selected)" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();" *ngIf="theFormControl">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngClass]="{'selected-option': buttonSelect.selected?.value === option[contentData.optionsStructure.valName]}" [disabled]="buttonSelect.selected?.value === option[contentData.optionsStructure.valName] && contentData.optionSelectedWillDisable" [value]="option[contentData.optionsStructure.valName]">
            {{option[contentData.optionsStructure.keyName]}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
```

Comment: I had the problem when a host modal component was dismissed. I had to use ngIf to check whether the control was still available when closing my dialog.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was I was missing the field name in the form builder:

```
  return this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      latLong: ['', [Validators.required]],
      details: ['', [Validators.required]],
      // missing field name!
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I forgot to initialize the form in `ngOnInit()` when using `[formControl]="customForm"`.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I left a formControlName empty (`formControlName=""`). Since I didn't need that extra form control, I deleted it and the error was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Only WinMerge made me find it (by comparison with a version that works).
I had a case problem on formGroupName.
Brackets around this word can lead to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had accidentally entered the control name when creating the formGroup:

```
getFormGroup(dataItem: any): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
        'Id': new FormControl(dataItem != null ? dataItem.Id : ''),
        'PsDepartmentId': new FormControl(dataItem != null ? dataItem.DepartmentId : '', Validators.required), //Accidentally used 'DepartmentId' on this line
        'IsActive': new FormControl(dataItem != null ? dataItem.IsActive : true)
    });
}
```

Then it failed in the html when I did

```
          <kendo-dropdownlist id="ps-dpts-dropdown" [data]="psDepartments" textField="ConCatedName" valueField="Id"
          [formControl]="formGroup.get('DepartmentId')" [valuePrimitive]="true">                  
          </kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular 13! `formControlName` should not empty.

```
formControlName=""
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because formControlName='' was empty.

Answer (score 0):

Change [formControl] to formControlName and simple give the name.
formControlName="name". Main thing to notice it should be under proper formGroupName or formArrayName.