# Angular 4 Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

Tags: javascript, angular, google-places-autocomplete

I have used google place API following [this tutorial](http://www.17educations.com/angularjs-2/google-map-api-angular-2-typescript/) but I am getting this error below:

> Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

[image: more detail about error in below screenshot]

I have tried also this all hint [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437726/angular-2-cannot-find-control-with-unspecified-name-attribute-on-formarrays)

**Code**

```
<div class="form-group"> 
<input #search
    type="text"
    placeholder="search for location"
    autocorrect="off"
    autocapitalize="off"
    spellcheck="off"
    class="form-control"
    [formControl]="searchControl"
    name="searchControl"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Dear my friend i pasted screenshot just because user can get clear idea about error.and error description is too much long.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should post some code, we're not mediums !

But seeing your error, I would say you're using reactive forms, and you forgot to create your reactive forms.

This means on your input, you have `[formControl]=""` or `formControlName=""` attribute, which can't find the corresponding variable.

Could you post the related code of that please ?

Comment: <div class="form-group">
                        <input placeholder="search for location" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off" type="text" class="form-control" #search [formControl]="searchControl" name="searchControl">
                     </div>

Comment: Man, you could have at least edited your question ... And I need your component's Typescript code too !

Comment: But could you try replacing `[formControl]="searchControl" ` with `formControlName="searchControl"` ?

Comment: No problem ! remember to mark your issue as resolved

Comment: <div class="form-group" [formGroup]="myGroup">
       <input placeholder="search for location" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off" type="text" class="form-control" #search formControlName="searchControl" name="searchControl">
                     </div>

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML code looks fine for me, I think this has occurred because you have not initialized *searchControl* variable in the corresponding JavaScript/TypeScript file.

Add this line into your class in JavaScript/TypeScript file

```
searchControl = new FormControl();
```